# Vlookup code (using Dictionary) to update the same row value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vlookup code that will update the text "UG" in a destination column if the result matches with the source sheet.

Example :The code compares "Sheet B" with "Sheet A" and if a match is found in "Sheet A" , it updates the text "UG" in a column in sheet A.

I want to make a small modification here.

Instead of updating the text "UG" in sheet A, I want to update the value that is there in the "Sheet B" in col B .

```
Sub UGvlookup()

Dim cl As Range, Dic As Object

Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Dic.Comparemode = vbTextCompare

With Sheets("Sheet A")
    For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then Dic.Add cl.Value, cl.Row
    Next cl
End With

With Sheets("Sheet B")
    For Each cl In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
            Sheets("Latency").Cells(Dic(cl.Value), 17) = "UG"
        End If
        If Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
            Sheets("Sheet A").Cells(Dic(cl.Value), 17) = "UG"
            Dic.Remove (cl.Value)
        End If
    Next cl
End With
```

Comment: You should also make sure to qualify the `Rows.Count` like you did with `.Range()`, eg `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "C")`

Comment: Where should I make the modification in my code?

Comment: In both `For Each cl` lines, you need to add the dot before `Rows.Count` to make sure the `Rows.Count` is being run on Sheet A, and Sheet B (respectively).  Otherwise, it's just going to count the rows on whatever your `ActiveSheet` is.  Note: This may not solve your issue, but it should help.  Also, did you write that code, or did you get it from somewhere? (Just trying to gauge your VBA understanding)

Comment: I'm pretty new to VBA and I got this code somewhere and edited little bit as per my need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you're after this:

```
Sub UGvlookup()

    Dim cl As Range, Dic As Object

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With Sheets("Sheet A")
        For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
            Dic.Item(cl.Value) = cl.Row
        Next cl
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet B")
        For Each cl In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Dic.Exists(cl.Value) Then
                Sheets("Latency").Cells(Dic(cl.Value), 17) = "UG"
                Sheets("Sheet A").Cells(Dic(cl.Value), 17) = cl.Offset(, 1) '<--| write in sheet A the value of sheet B cell adjacent to the "current" one
                Dic.Remove (cl.Value)
            End If
        Next cl
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a small modification..this code ignores the duplicate values and updates only for unique values. Which line does this and how do i remove this?

Comment: please be more specific: of which data do you want not to ignore duplicates?

Comment: If Sheet 1 col A has value 1,2,3,4,5 (source) and Sheet 1 col A has value 1,2,2,2,2 (source)..it will put the text in the first 2 which it finds and will not update it for 3 two's. but I want it to update for other 3 two's as well

Comment: how can Sheet 1 col A have two different values group? please edit your question with clear and verifiable data

Comment: extrmely sorry.. 
If Sheet1 col A has value 1,2,3,4,5 (source) and Sheet2 col A has value 1,2,2,2,2 (destination)..the code will update the values that sheet1 col B has into Sheet2 col B..here in this case, "2" is the only matching data..so the code will just take the text that "2" has in col B and update it in sheet2 against the FIRST "2" only and not the other "2" which is below that as those are duplicate values. The change I want to make is, it should even check for the other "2" below it.

Comment: any suggestion @user3598756